# Change Directive variable inside a directive is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am trying to change a controller variable inside a directive and this is my code:

the main controller is :

```
angular.module("app").controller('vehicleManagementController', ['$scope', 'toastr', '$filter' ,
function ($scope, toastr, $filter) {
    .....
    $scope.filteredDevices = //Some List
    $scope.allDevices = [];
 }
}]);
```

and the directive is :

```
angular.module('app').directive('advanceSearchDirective', ['deviceAdvancedSearchService', 'mapService', function (deviceAdvancedSearchService, mapService) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    controller: 'myDirectiveController',
    scope: { filteredDevices: '=filteredDevices' },
    templateUrl: '/app/templates/advanceSearchDirective.html'
};
 }]);

angular.module("app").controller(myDirectiveController( $scope) {
    $scope.search = function() {
       $scope.filteredDevices = [];
      $scope.$apply();  
     }
});
```

the thing is it faild to run the apply() method through [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply) error.
and here how i am using it :

```
 <advance-search-directive filtered-devices="filteredDevices" model="$parent"></advance-search-directive>
```

I have access to `$scope.filteredDevices` inside the directive controller but when i change its value it doesn't change in the main controller. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add a jsfiddle or the content of /app/templates/advanceSearchDirective.html?

Comment: @Michelem nothing related happens in the template.

Comment: Does replacing `$scope.filteredDevices = []`; with `$scope.filteredDevices.length = 0;` help?

Comment: Is that $scope.$apply(); is nessesary for you? I didn't undestand this moment, why it's there - when you change variable in scope, $apply called automatically. Thats why angular says that "apply already runninfg". Usially it used to notify angular about non-angular changes, like jQuery plugins values.

Comment: BTW, are there any messages in console?

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?
Have you tried the **bindToController: true** [this link](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to save the changes on the parent controller scope you should use

> scope:false,

change the directive to :

```
     return {
       restrict: "E",
       controller: 'myDirectiveController',
       scope: false,
       templateUrl: '/app/templates/advanceSearchDirective.html'
   };
```

[here is an useful article](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/angularjs-understanding-directive-scope) .